# How to pass errors in Spring Controller/Model to a view file

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

How do I pass errors to a view file from a Controller implemented using Spring MVC? These errors are not form errors. Just business logic errors that will be shown inside a div in the "JSP" view.

Here is the controller action I have:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processLoginForm(HttpServletRequest request, LoginForm loginForm, 
BindingResult result, @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Map model) 
{
    loginForm = (LoginForm) model.get("loginForm");

    String gotoURL = request.getParameter("gotoURL");

    if (gotoURL == null || gotoURL == "") 
    {
        String errorMessage = "No Redirect URL Specified"; 
        return "loginerror";//loginerror is the view file I want to pass my error to.
    }
    model.put("loginForm", loginForm);
    return "loginsuccess";
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Use `ModelMap` instead of hackishly suppressing warnings.

Comment: How do I change my method signature to use ModelMap. Sorry..Spring Newbie here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your method signature :

```
public String processLoginForm(HttpServletRequest request, LoginForm loginForm,
                 BindingResult result, ModelMap model)
```

You can put the error message in the [`ModelMap`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/ui/ModelMap.html) and forward it to the *loginerror* page.

```
if (gotoURL == null || "".equals(gotoURL)) 
{
    final String errorMessage = "No Redirect URL Specified"; 
    modelMap.addAttribute("errorMessage ", errorMessage);
    return "loginerror";//loginerror is the view file I want to pass my error to.
}
```

You can fetch that in the `div` using EL.

```
<div>${errorMessage}</div>
```

Comment: I was getting this error: The method addAttribute(String, String) is undefined for the type Map. How do I change my method signature to include ModelMap?

Comment: Side Question:
Is there a way I can do a check like
if (!empty(errorMessage))
{ //Displayerror div } else { //Hide it } in JSP

 //Display error DIV

Comment: No cannot do that , what you can do is you can have a separate JSP file which will have the div and include it in JSP based on the this if condition , you can use JSTL for that.

Comment: Oh.. Wow.. Can I atleast pass error=1 as a query string to the view, when I am returning "loginerror" view? Ex: return "loginerror?error=1"

Comment: Why you need to pass query String , that string you passed will be used to resolve a view it is not an URL. You can put anything in the ModelMap.

Comment: The reason `ModelMap` is provided is so that we can use the traditional `put` method of maps instead of the rather verbose `addAttribute`. You can just do `modelMap.put("errorMessage ", errorMessage);`

Answer (score 2):

Your method is

> public String processLoginForm(HttpServletRequest request, LoginForm
>   loginForm,  BindingResult result, @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Map
>   model)

The method @The New Idiot explained is

> public String processLoginForm(HttpServletRequest request, LoginForm
>   loginForm,
>                    BindingResult result, ModelMap model)

See that the Map model is replaced with ModelMap model

If you use this method, then you can use  model.addAttribute to add error messages

Answer (score 1):

You can use Spring support for exception handling..

`HandlerExceptionResolver` or `@ExceptionHandler`

@adarshr

[Link](http://steveliles.github.io/configuring_global_exception_handling_in_spring_mvc.html)

Hope it will be of some use.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Perhaps you could elaborate your answer by providing examples and/or quoting from the Spring reference manual.

Comment: http://steveliles.github.io/configuring_global_exception_handling_in_spring_mvc.html

Comment: Once the link dies, your answer won't help. Copy the important informations here with the link.